# Append tailwind classes on React Data Table's column headers

Tags: reactjs, styled-components, tailwind-css, react-data-table-component

I am planning to integrate my Tailwind CSS styles to a jbetancur React Data Table (see https://github.com/jbetancur/react-data-table-component) as a custom style.

I would like to put the TW classes inside the `customStyles` attribute of the Datatable so that I can put a custom style to its table headers, but I can't get it to work. So far this only accepts style objects.

Comment: Have you had any luck?

Comment: @d9h none yet. I just created a custom datatable component where I can apply the tailwind classes.